# Powershell progress bar when scrolling

Tags: powershell, progress

I am trying to add a progress bar to a PowerShell script I am working on, using `Write-Progress`

The problem I have is that the script calls some programs that output a lot of text, causing the PowerShell console to scroll.
When this scrolling happens, the progress bar also gets scrolled up, causing it to be hidden.

How can I make the progress bar cover the scrolling text, being always visible? The output of those programs needs to be visible, so hiding the output is not a solution.

Comment: Create a GUI with separate controls for text output and progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to go through the documentation of PS Progress Bar.

It is not recommended to use it for scroll-able things, you can use some other forms for the same.  You can use *inner progress bar* to fulfill your requirement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "inner progress bar"?